# implement the logic to enable to generate PDF button on Quote object when condition met

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

I have created a button on Quote object to generate PDF and need to implement the below when the Approval Notice Field met the condition :
Approval Notice = null.  No error message and will generate PDF
Approval Notice = not null.  Error message and does not generate PDF

JS:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 

var c = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
c.id = "{!Quote.Id}"; 
var status = "{!Quote__c.Approval_Notice__c}"; 
if(status = ' ') 
window.location = 'apex/QuotePDFCallerPage?id='+c.id; 
else 
alert('Quote has not been approved can not generate PDF');
```

Please let me know if i am doing it correctly or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have logic bugs and a lot of extra fluff in your code. You simply need to do this:

```
if({!ISBLANK(Quote__c.Approval_Notice__c)}) {
    window.location = "/apex/QuotePDFCallerPage?id={!Quote__c.Id}";
} else {
    alert("Quote has not been approved yet, so you cannot generate the PDF.")
}
```